# Beaglebone Board not started after Booting

Tags: debian, beagleboard

I booted my beaglebone wireless board with a Debian Image, but after booting it does not start, only the power LED is glowing.

What steps are needed to start my board?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. You provide very little information in your post, so it is unlikely that anyone can help you. You could for example tell us how you installed Debian and what version you used.

Comment: I follow all the steps given in  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/2016-06-29_BBGW/  and used BBGW-blank-debian-8.6-seeed-gcp-iot-armhf-2016-10-19-4gb.img.xz image.